# UISegmentedControl writing text labels problem

Tags: objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

Goodday,

I got the following problem with this code:

```
-(void)textpopup:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    int nummer = sender.tag;

    if (sender.tag) {
       if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 || sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
           beoordeling = [[UITextField alloc] init];
           beoordeling.frame = CGRectMake(50 , nummer * 117 + 275 , scrollView.frame.size.width - 100 , 35);
           beoordeling.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
           beoordeling.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
           beoordeling.tag = nummer;
           [scrollView addSubview:beoordeling];


       }
        if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 || sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 3){
            if (beoordeling.tag == sender.tag) {
                [beoordeling removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

i shall explain the scenario. I got some dynamic UISegmentedControls. At the moment there are 12 of them. At the first 2 segments chosen, a textfield needs to popup. This goes well. But after choosing the first 2 segments for a while and when i go to segments 2 and 3, sometimes the textfields won't remove.

I expected that the textfields which are written when i push segment 0 and 1 are removed when segment 2 and 3 are pushed.

Am i missing something?

**EDIT:**
At first i want to say, that i never know in advance how many UITextFields i got. When segments 0 and 1 are chosen, a UITextField needs to popup to that corresponding UISegmentedControl. And when segments 2 and 3 are chosen, the UITextField needs to stay away. But i got that fixed now in the following way.

```
-(void)textpopup:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    int nummer = sender.tag;


       if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 || sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){

           // Before i add a new UITextField, the old one has to be removed.
           UITextField *text = (UITextField *)[beoordeling viewWithTag:sender.tag];
           [text removeFromSuperView];   

           beoordeling = [[UITextField alloc] init];
           beoordeling.frame = CGRectMake(50 , nummer * 117 + 275 , scrollView.frame.size.width - 100 , 35);
           beoordeling.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
           beoordeling.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
           beoordeling.tag = nummer;
           [scrollView addSubview:beoordeling];


       }
        else if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 || sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 3) {

            UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)[beoordeling viewWithTag:sender.tag];
            tf.text = nil;
            [tf removeFromSuperview];

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `if` should be an `else if`, because it should execute only if the first one doesn't (the selected index can't be both 0 and 2).

What you're trying to do depends on how you've defined `beoordeling`. I suggest having it as an instance variable, possibly even an `IBOutlet`. Release in your class's `dealloc`. Then, in the first `if` clause, write

```
if (!beoordeling) {
    beoordeling = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    // Other setup
}
[scrollView addSubview:beoordeling];
```

<strike>I don't quite understand why you're checking for the tag, but to remove in the second `if`, just call `removeFromSubview`.</strike>

Do all your segmented controls invoke the same behavior? If you have only one `beorrdeling` that you're setting the tag on, then you don't need to bother checking for the tag. Just add/remove it, using `removeFromSubview`. If you have as many of text fields as segmented controls, maybe KVC would be what you want. If your segmented controls' tags go from 0–11, you might have `beoordeling0`, `beoordeling1`, `beoordeling2`, and so on. Then, to get the one you want, use something like this:

```
beoordeling = (UITextField *)[self valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"beoordeling%d", sender.tag]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to achieve here, but you do need to release your UITextField object beoordeling or you will leak.  AddSubview adds one to the retain count, so should be safe to release straight away:

```
[scrollView addSubview:beoordeling];
[beoordeling release];
```